# How i can create alert when time runs out in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Please help me with the code . How i can create alert when time runs out in this code. i want to set alert on when time runs out .

```js
function makeTimer() {

  //    var endTime = new Date("29 April 2018 9:56:00 GMT+01:00");  
  var endTime = new Date("29 April 2020 9:56:00 GMT+01:00");
  endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

  var now = new Date();
  now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

  var timeLeft = endTime - now;

  var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400);
  var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

  if (hours < "10") {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  if (minutes < "10") {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (seconds < "10") {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }


  $("#minutes").html(minutes + "<span>Minutes</span>");
  $("#seconds").html(seconds + "<span>Seconds</span>");

}

setInterval(function() {
  makeTimer();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="minutes"></span> <span id="seconds"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test

```js
const pad = n => ("0" + n).slice(-2);

var endTime = new Date();
// uncomment below
//    endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes() + 15);// 15 minutes
// remove next line, it is just to show how the count down works without waiting 15 minutes
endTime.setSeconds(endTime.getSeconds() + 10);// 10 seconds
endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

function makeTimer() {


  var now = new Date();
  now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

  var timeLeft = endTime - now;

  var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400);
  var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

  $("#minutes").html(pad(minutes) + " <span>Minute" + (minutes === 1 ? "" : "s") + "</span>");
  $("#seconds").html(pad(seconds) + " <span>Second" + (seconds === 1 ? "" : "s") + "</span>");

  if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0) {
    console.log("Done")
    clearInterval(tId);
  }
}

const tId = setInterval(makeTimer, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="minutes"></span> <span id="seconds"></span>
```

Comment: Hi, your code is working perfectly, 
but the  purpose of my work has not been fulfilled. I want the 15 minutes countdown timer when user load the web page it should start when it complete should occur the alert message.
just simple please help with code

Comment: Where is 15 minutes mentioned anywhere? If you want 15 minutes, create a date, add 15 minutes ...  See update

Comment: Great. Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function,you can simply check the values of hours, minutes and seconds.As you already have it, you can simply put an if condition to check whether the hour is 0 and minute is 0 and second is 0. Then in that condition you can simply send an alert message.